# FastCGI, Lighttpd Interface Error/Operational Error

Tags: django, fastcgi, lighttpd

I am getting an Interface Error/ Operational Error while running my Django application with FastCGI.On checking the access log ( of lighttpd) i find these errors pop up which are usually related to closing some db connection or the other.
The browser displays one of the two things - Unhandled Exception or Connection Terminated unsuccessfully message. Upon refreshing the page once ( usually) the errors seem to go off.
How can I prevent this from happening ? The system really behaves in an erratic fashion.

Answer (score 1):

There could be 2 reasons for this problem occuring.
1. Not all URLs mentioned in your urls.py are reversing properly.
2. This is the tough part - Somewhere in the project an import is failing. It may be importing a method which does not exist.

I faced the same problem and I discovered that there were many imports like the ones mentioned in the second point.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and wrote my own solution after finding nothing from the web. Please check my blogpost here: [Simple Python Utility to check all Imports in your project](http://nandakishore.posterous.com/simple-djangopython-utility-to-check-all-the)

Ofcourse this will only help you to get to the solution of the original issue pretty quickly and not the actual solution for your problem by itself.